# Javascript to add button to next row in a table

Tags: javascript, button, html-table, cell

I am trying to get an add button to appear on the next row of each row when the add button is clicked. currently I am getting an empty textfield in the cell where I would like the add button to appear. what would i have to change in my code to get the add button instead of the text field when the add button is clicked?

For the add button's JavaScript I currently have:

```
     // button cell
  var cellRightSel = row.insertCell(3);
  var bt = document.createElement('input');
  bt.name = 'addBt' + iteration;
  bt.id = 'addBt' + iteration; 
  cellRightSel.appendChild(bt);
```

and the html for the page is:

```
<table border="1" id="tblSample">
<tr>
<th colspan="3">Sample table</th>
</tr>
<tr>

<td><input type="text" name="txtRow1"
 id="txtRow1" size="40"  /></td>



<td><input type="text" name="txtRow2"
 id="txtRow3" size="40"  /></td>



<td>
<select name="selRow0">
<option value="value0">text zero</option>
<option value="value1">text one</option>
</select>
</td>


<td><input type="button" value="Add" onclick="addRowToTable();" name="addBt0" /></td>


</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 3):

`bt.type = "button"`

You forgot to make it a button.

Alternatively you could do

`var bt = document.createElement('button');`

to make a `<button>` instead.

Comment: Careful with dynamically created button elements, setting the value property in IE changes the caption (i.e. text that appears on the button). Other browsers understand that the value and content are different things. To add the caption, append a text node.